# Kubuntu:16.04.3: how do I install/use Intel microcode?

Tags: intel, microcode

I've read several reviews of Ubuntu family and what I can gather it should be available in Driver Management inside Settings but on my setup, it's not showing.

my setup: dual Xeon CPU on a server board (C602-based).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel Xeon may be too old to get firmware updates, but here goes...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update # update the software database

sudo apt-get install intel-microcode # install intel-microcode

reboot # reboot the computer

either one of the following:

dmesg | grep -i microcode # review the log since boot

grep -i microcode /var/log/syslog* # review syslog

Looking to see if the microcode got loaded, or if it
indicates that it's not required for your processor.
```

If it's not required:

```
sudo apt-get purge intel-microcode # to uninstall it
```

To use `intel-microcode`, you don't do anything, other than to note that it's working on your processor.

Comment: I check if the microcode is getting loaded and I can see 2 entries. The last entry is something about Microcode Update Driver version 2.2. I suppose that means it's getting loaded? thanks again

Comment: @mrjayviper you'll have to look at dmesg or syslog closer to see if any of the processors received a code update.

Comment: Any tips on how can I "look closer  to see if the CPU received a code update"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mrjayviper look at dmesg or syslog immediately after booting, and look for lines that indicate that processor 1/2/3/4 is being loaded with microcode, bringing it up to revision xyz. Or, find the message indicating that intel-microcode is not used on this processor. You should be able to `grep` for the word `microcode` to see it. `grep -i microcode /var/log/syslog*` or `dmesg | grep -i microcode`.

Comment: Xeon just got updates a few days ago because of the [Meltdown and Spectre](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/speculativeexecution) exploits.